# Python SQLite 3: How do I formate query output?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I have a SQLite DB which outputs the content into a tkinter grid. The problem I have is, that as soon as I use a space the output will be shown in {program brackets}.

Is there any way to formate the output?

```
cursor.execute('SELECT NAME from CALENDAR')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
namelist = []

for i in range(len(rows)):
    namelist.append(Label(main, text=rows[i]))
    namelist[i].grid(row=3+i, column=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rows[i]` is a list, not a string. When Tkinter tries to convert a list to a string it will put curly braces around data. The solution is to convert your data to a string before inserting it in a widget.

I'm guessing that in your case it would look something like this:

```
namelist.append(Label(main, text=" ".join(rows[i]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast help. Works perfectly!